# Pandas column: applying a function

Tags: python, pandas, apply, axis

I have a pandas data frame df

```
df:

GROUP VALUE
 1     5
 2     2
 1     10
 2     20
 1     7
```

And I am trying to apply the following function on one of the column

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels import robust
import numpy as np

def madout(x):
    mad = robust.mad(x)
    median = np.median(x)
    mad_s = (abs(x - median / mad))
    return mad_s

df.VALUE.apply(madout)
```

but receiving an error despite my several attempts

AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0. 
Please help

Comment: Which line is throwing that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` is going to apply the function to every element of the column `df.VALUE`.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
In [8]: madout(df.VALUE)
Out[8]: 
0     3.426191
1     0.426191
2     8.426191
3    18.426191
4     5.426191
Name: VALUE, dtype: float64
```